# Creating a user on heroku console Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-console

I'm a beginner working through the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I'm trying to create a user into the Heroku console: [Here is the tut i following: (35:21)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxcu_IzUieg&list=PLTEIIaBCEjOts1A2nwIlyoAn8l_3_WWWq&index=40)

```
irb(main):001:0> User.create!(:name => "Example User", :email => "example@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")
```

I'm getting this error! I don't understand the `PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist`

```
PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum

    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `async_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1286:in `column_definitions'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `columns'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:243:in `column_defaults'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:482:in `initialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `create!'
    from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have the migrations in place, please run the following

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `users` table is missing, Did you run the `rake db:migrate` in production? I'm not that familiar with Heroku, but normally you can run it as

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```